# Hide method from enumeration

Tags: javascript, extjs

I want to add a method to every object.

When I just set `Object.prototype.somefunction = ...`, it will come up when somebody enumerates the object using the usual pattern:

```
for (i in o){
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        // do something with object
    }
}
```

I tried to set it higher up the prototype chain, but that is not possible (at least not possible in Chrome):

> TypeError: Cannot set property 'blah' of undefined

Can I set some flag or something on the method so that it won't get enumerated, just like the native methods won't? (Or at least make `hasOwnProperty()` return `false`.)

---

**Update:** Sorry, I didn't look at it properly. I am using the ExtJS Framework and the object I was looking at had been processed by Ext.apply() which does the following:

```
for(var p in c){
    o[p] = c[p];
}
```

That's where the "own property" flag gets lost.

So I guess I have no chance (in ECMAScript < 5) to inject a method into all objects that behaves like a native one?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understand correctly. `hasOwnProperty` is needed exactly for this case, and enumerating an object via

```
for (i in o){
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        // do something with object
    }
}
```

should not include methods from `Object.prototype`. Can you please make a working example where you see this behaviour?

I also do not understand what you mean by

> I tried to set it higher up the
>   prototype chain

as `Object.prototype` is the root of the chain, so you cannot get any higher.

In short, the solution is doing exactly what you claim you have done. If this does not work, probably you have made a mistake or found a bug.

Comment: +1 for pointing that out, so I found the real reason (see question update).

Comment: I don't know the internals of ExtJS, but the passage you mention seems a way for trouble. There are safer ways to copy objects and keep their protoype chain. If ExtJS just copies **all** properties, I think you are at a loss, even in ES5. But I believe the designers of ExtJS know what they are doing, so it is possible (maybe?) that you shouldn't call `Ext.apply()` in your context? Otherwise, I think you should file a bug.

Comment: Probably extending the prototype of Object like I did is something one shouldn't do, so I think it's ok they didn't took that into account. The problem shows up in the way that suddenly *all* objects created by Ext.apply have my new method as an enumerable property.

Comment: Dear AndreaKR, I am not sure if I understand correctly. Are you using Ext.apply directly, or is it being used through some other Ext functions? In the former case, I think it would be easier to write your own function to copy objects which does this in a sane way. In the second case, you actually have a problem. I still htink that if this is the case, they probably have a bug, but I don't know how you are supposed to use ExtJS, so I cannot really tell.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean. If a method/property is attached to the prototype, `hasOwnProperty` will return false. See this code:

```
function Con(){this.enumerableProp = true;};
Con.prototype.fun = function(){return 'that\'s funny'};

var fun = new Con;

alert(fun.hasOwnProperty('fun')); //=> false
alert(fun.hasOwnProperty('enumerableProp')); //=> true
```

So, what do you mean?

Comment: +1 for pointing that out, so I found the real reason (see question update).

Answer (score 0):

Make a base class and make all other classes extend it. Add the method to the base class.

Answer (score 0):

ES5 has `Object.getOwnPropertyNames()` for this:

```
Object.prototype.lolwat = 42;
var obj = {
  'foo': 1,
  'bar': 2
}; 
Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj); // ['bar', 'foo']
```

To see where it is supported: http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

However, `for-in` combined with a `hasOwnProperty` check should work too.

Answer (score 0):

You get that error because there *is* nothing higher up the prototype chain.

Of note also is that adding to Object's prototype is not really recommended unless absolutely necessary for some reason

Edit: actually, my original answer was incorrect - as the others have pointed out, your object should *not* have that as own property if it's in Object's prototype.

In any case, if you want to create a prototype chain (or more importantly, avoid changing Object's prototype), you'll want to create your own class:

```
function MyBaseClass(){
}
MyBaseClass.prototype = new Object();
MyBaseClass.prototype.someMethod = function() { /* your method */ };

var o = new MyBaseClass();
o.hasOwnProperty('someMethod') //should be false
```